# Android app interaction with fitness band

Tags: android, api, sdk

I am trying to make the fitness app in android but for that I need to make a communication between the android app and fitness band.
Is there any way we can interact with any fitness band like Mi band or others through our own android app using some public API or SDK. By interaction mean I can sync it's data with my own android app like step count, kilometer walk/run etc.

Comment: if it has bluetooth then you can use it

Comment: http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/android-bluetooth-connection-demo

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can interact with fitness band using your own android app. Mi provides sdk to do that for mi bands only.

https://github.com/pangliang/miband-sdk-android